# resizable rectangle with user touch events on Android

Tags: android

I want to create a rectangular shape that will be resized with the touches of the user. Look at this Flex sample.
 http://www.objecthandles.com/
i want to develop this kind of android application. i am looking for a good tutorial. 
(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android/16359284#16359284

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://tools.android.com/recent/resizesupport

[How to create a resizable rectangle with user touch events on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android)

Comment: thanx, but i am looking for a good tutorial or samlpe application