# A follow-up to drawing resizable rectangle

Tags: java, android

Here is the previous question:
[How to create a resizable rectangle with user touch events on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android)

Forget about moving the rectangle, the rectangle itself does not get drawn. Below is my code. I do not get any errors, but I cannot see the rectangle or the corners at all.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private ArrayList<ColorBall> colorballs = new ArrayList<ColorBall>();
    private int groupID = -1;
    private int ballID = 0;
    private Canvas canvas;
    Point[] pts = new Point[4];
    int left, top, right, bottom;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private BitmapDrawable bmDrawable;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true);
        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true);
        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------//

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (pts[3] == null) {
            return;
        }
        int left, top, right, bottom;
        left = pts[0].x;
        top = pts[0].y;
        right = pts[0].x;
        bottom = pts[0].y;

        for (int i = 1; i < pts.length; i++) {
            left = left > pts[i].x ? pts[i].x : left;
            top = top > pts[i].y ? pts[i].y : top;
            right = right < pts[i].x ? pts[i].x : right;
            bottom = bottom < pts[i].y ? pts[i].y : bottom;
        }

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        // draw stroke
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AADB1255"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        canvas.drawRect(left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);

        //fill the rectangle
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55DB1255"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);

        canvas.drawRect(left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);



        // draw corners
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
        bmDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);

        // draw balls on canvas
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < colorballs.size(); i++) {
            ColorBall ball = colorballs.get(i);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmDrawable.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), paint);
            canvas.drawText("" + (i + 1), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), paint);
        }
    }



}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drawview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.androiddraw.DrawView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have the ColorBall class with all the proper setters and getters. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I see that you call "this.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);" in your onDraw method. Set this in your constructor because the way you have it, the call to setBackgroundColor will invalidate your layout and cause a redraw. You can get into a recursive invalidate, draw, invalidate, draw situation. See if this helps out.

If that doesn't fix your problem, then you might have to look deeper into your onDraw method. Try starting out small to see if parts of your code gets rendered properly in the layout preview.

Another thing to check for is making sure that in your Activity.onCreate() you are setting setContentView(R.layout..). Sometimes we forget and wonder why nothing is on the screen.

Finally, I've seen more custom layouts defined as below. Maybe you can try this syntax.

```
<com.example.androiddraw.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/drawview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you WindsurferOak. The OnDraw had the issue. Fixed it and now it works perfectly.