# Condition for resizing a rectangle fails

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have found that the following code fails when I'm trying to implement a resizing rectangle:

```
 for(int i=0;i<colorBalls.size();i++)
    {
        int centerX=colorBalls.get(i).getX()+colorBalls.get(i).getWidthOfBall();
        int centerY=colorBalls.get(i).getY()+colorBalls.get(i).getHeightOfBall();
        double radCircle=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-centerX,2)+Math.pow(y-centerX, 2));
        if(radCircle<colorBalls.get(i).getWidthOfBall())
        {
            mBallID=colorBalls.get(i).getId();
            Log.d("RectangleView", "ID of ball selected "+mBallID);
            if(mBallID==1 || mBallID==3)
                mGroupID=2;
            else
                mGroupID=1;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
    }
```

I know because in the following code,only `Resizing balls 2 and 4` is printed but the other one is never printed in my `Logcat`:

```
 colorBalls.get(mBallID).setX(x);
    colorBalls.get(mBallID).setY(y);
    if (mGroupID == 1) {
        Log.d("RectangleView","Resizing balls 2 and 4");
        colorBalls.get(1).setX(colorBalls.get(0).getX());
        colorBalls.get(1).setY(colorBalls.get(2).getY());
        colorBalls.get(3).setX(colorBalls.get(2).getX());
        colorBalls.get(3).setY(colorBalls.get(0).getY());
    }
    if(mGroupID==2)
    {
        Log.d("RectangleView", "Resizing balls 1 and 3");
        colorBalls.get(0).setX(colorBalls.get(1).getX());
        colorBalls.get(0).setY(colorBalls.get(3).getY());
        colorBalls.get(2).setX(colorBalls.get(3).getX());
        colorBalls.get(2).setY(colorBalls.get(1).getY());
    }
    invalidate();
```

My code is an implementation of the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android/17807469#17807469)

The points are rendered in anti clockwise fashion,0 is the leftmost edge,1 is below 0,2 is on the same line as 1,to the right and 3 is above 2.

## EDIT:

Modified the code:

```
int centerX=colorBalls.get(i).getX()+colorBalls.get(i).getWidthOfBall()/2;//here
        int centerY=colorBalls.get(i).getY()+colorBalls.get(i).getHeightOfBall()/2;//here
        double radCircle=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-centerX,2)+Math.pow(y-centerY, 2));//here
        if(radCircle<colorBalls.get(i).getWidthOfBall())
        {
            mBallID=colorBalls.get(i).getId();
            Log.d("RectangleView", "ID of ball selected "+mBallID);
            if(mBallID==1 || mBallID==3)
                mGroupID=2;
            else
                mGroupID=1;
            invalidate();
            break;
```

Comment: Well, with just a quick glance, I see a couple problems with your code: The centers should be the coordinates plus _half_ the dimension (you're missing /2 on both lines). And Math.pow(y-centerX, 2) should be Math.pow(y-centerY, 2).

Comment: @MikeM. thanks man,made the changes and it works perfectly now...guess a fresh eye always helps

Comment: Sure,post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just has a few minor math errors. In calculating centerX/centerY, you need to add *half* the width/height, like so:

```
int centerX = colorBalls.get(i).getX() + colorBalls.get(i).getWidthOfBall() / 2;
int centerY = colorBalls.get(i).getY() + colorBalls.get(i).getHeightOfBall() / 2;
```

And, in figuring the radius, you accidentally subtracted centerX instead of centerY from the y coordinate. Should be:

```
double radCircle = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-centerX, 2) + Math.pow(y-centerY, 2));
```