# Resize Grid item in android with touch event

Tags: android

Im looking for a way to implement something like this :

[image: ImageGrid]

the resize method of column must be exact same like when we resize Widget.

like this :

[image: widget]

ive tried "jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary"  but couldnt compile it under android:minSdkVersion="7".
Also the "maurycyw/StaggeredGridView" didn't help either because the height of coloumns are
equal.
"TouchImageview" is good , but there isnt any handle around image when resizing , and dont no should i use it in grid adaptor.

this is my code so far for creating layout and adding event for user when holding elemnt long enough :

```
     gl = new GridLayout(Home.this);
        gl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        gl.setOrientation(0);
        gl.setColumnCount(3);
        gl.setRowCount(3);

        text = new TextView[9];

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            text[i] = new TextView(Home.this);
            text[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));
            text[i].setTextSize(25);
            text[i].setPadding(50, 25, 10, 25);
            gl.addView(text[i]);
        }

        setContentView(gl);
  text[item].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            int pos = item;

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 // The Sticker should appear here for imageview or textview instead of bellow code 
  text[1].setPadding(100, 100, 100, 100);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check That http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain thanks for link ,  but i couldnt figured out to apply that around the box and not inside it.

Comment: Hi@AhadPorkar, have you found an approach for this? Please share if any