# How to create a resizable circle with user touch events?

Tags: android, shapes, android-drawable

I am trying to create a circle shape that will be resized on **onTouchEvent**.

I have followed [resizable rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807469/2638871) post, but I think due to lack of mathematics knowledge, I am not getting how to create resizeable circle.

I have tried changing

```
canvas.drawRect(
    left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
    top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
    right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
    bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
```

to **canvas.drawCircle()**; it creates the circle but not quite what I wanted.

Can you please tell me is there any thing like this already implemented or what points should I follow to convert this rectangle example to resizable circle.

Comment: You are drawing it on a map ???

Comment: I have done it for GoogleMap, and used SeekBar to resize the Circle, if you want I can share my solution.

Comment: @SalmanKhan, no I am trying to create it on custom view.

Comment: what does `colorballs` collection stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the center of circle will be:

```
float cx = (left + right) / 2f; 
float cy = (top + bottom) / 2f;
```

-- quite obvious. Radius can be calculated using `Math.hypot()`:

```
float radius = Math.hypot(top - bottom, right - left) / 2f;
```

Thus, we have center and radius to draw a circle:

```
drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
```