# How to resize line with user touch event in android?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

[image]I need to draw line and edit it by resize,delete etc.,I need to resize the  line with user touch event.Currently i am able to draw line

```
  private void onDrawLine(Canvas canvas) {

    float dx = Math.abs(mx - mStartX);
    float dy = Math.abs(my - mStartY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {

        canvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, mx, my, mPaint);
        /*bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, mStartX, mStartY, null);        
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, mx, my, null);  */      

    }
}

private void onTouchEventLine(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            isDrawing = true;
            mStartX = mx;
            mStartY = my;
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

             isDrawing = false;
             mCanvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, mx, my, mPaintFinal);
             invalidate();
            break;
    }
}
```

For Resize,i found for rectangle i need to implement for line.Here is the link for resize rectangle with user touch event

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807469/2365507

Please help me

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? "How to resize canvas line" has completely no sense...

Comment: @pskink i need to draw line or arrow  between two icons and if icons will placed on some other place using drag.i need to resize the line to that new positions of icon

Comment: maybe other people will understand you since i cant get what you really mean ...

Comment: A bit late, but can be helpful to others. Derived from answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android/17807469#17807469

Answer (score 1):

Get the newX, newY points of new position, where you want line to be and drawLine again

```
canvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, newX, newY , mPaint);
```

and call `invalidate()` to redraw on canvas

Comment: Please give some example

Comment: It is hard to find example of exactly what you want, but i can explain if you are stuck at any point

Comment: when i have to get newX and newY values?is it in ACTION_UP?I tried to get new x and y values,line gets redrawn from the endpoint.but i want to resize the old line

Comment: do u mean "animate to large size" by "resize"

Comment: you will not do it in onTouchEventLine(), but from other touchEvent method. Like the icons's touch event/drag event

Comment: How can i implement in onTouchEvent with event.getX() and event.getY()??I am unable to move this discussion to chat,will you?

Comment: please check this Nguyen Minh Binh answer,he resize the rectangle with user touch event,but i need to resize line.how can i achieve??http://stackoverflow.com/a/17807469/2365507