# Draw shapes dynamic

Tags: android, canvas

I am developing an application for technical drawing and I need to add a few tools to draw lines, circles, rectangles and corners. Now I can draw lines and free hand drawing but I cannot draw circles, rectangles and corners. I found in lot of websites how to draw it but static, I mean, draw the shape in the position you pre-set or the position where you touch but I need to know how to draw, for example, a circle in the position I touch and make it bigger than I separate my fingers. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: You should read up on gestures

Comment: I do not know how to implement gestures to draw. Do you know any tutorial or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two variables x and y, then every time you touch the screen set x and y to that value, while drawing draw the circle with coordinates x and y.

If you are drawing and you just want to keep a painted circle, you can paint the circle and add it inside your canvas on x and y, then the next time you touch the screen a new circle will be painted on x and y and the old one will remain painted.

Are you using `Canvas` ? if so you can find out how to do this [here (Canvas documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and [here (Bitmap documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html). Depending on your situation you can create a new `Bitmap` and assign it to `Canvas` then draw on the `Canvas`and inside your bitmap you will have your desired circles and other shapes, on the next drawing frame, draw new shapes and the changes will remain.

Edit: In order to have dynamic radius follow this logic, when you touch the screen, set x and y to that point (the center of the circle), while moving the finger on the screen, calculate the radius comparing to x and y, when lifting your finger apply the drawing on the bitmap as told above.

Some code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //If I'm not wrong this is how to calculate radius,
            //I'm at work and can't test this now, you can use your way
            int distanceX = (int) event.getX() -x;
            int distanceY = (int) event.getY() -y;
            radius = sqrt(distanceX *distanceX + distanceY *distanceY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Draw circle inside your bitmap here

            //This is like a flag to notify the program that no new shape is being drawn
            x = -1;
            break;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //A new shape is being drawn
    if (x != -1)
        //In here you place a switch to decide which shape you are drawing
        //for this example i assume circle
        canvas.drawCircle(radius, x, y, paint);
}
```

When you are lifting your finger the new circle should be painted on your bitmap so you don't have to add extra code for each new circle.

Edit2: I will add more code with the `Bitmap` and `Canvas` method i described.

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
Canvas myCanvas;

//Constructor
public myActivity(Bundle bundle) //or whatever your constructor is
{
    myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
}
```

Now anything you draw on "myCanvas" will be applied to "myBitmap", when `ACTION_UP` activates draw circle on "myCanvas" which is drawn on the `draw` function.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    myCanvas.drawCircle(radius, x, y, paint);

    x = -1;
    break;
```

Comment: I am using canvas. I was reading and now I can draw the circle but I want to make it with a dynamic radius. I read taht [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android/17807469#17807469) but I cannot draw the rectangle without the balls. Any idea?

Comment: @AbelSuviri I edited my answer with more explanation

Comment: I test your code and I change it a bit to fit my code but it does not work properly. I get a big circle allways at the left side of the screen and I am unable to move it to the position and when I stop touching the screen I get a small circle in the position I touched and the big circle dissapears

Comment: @AbelSuviri the big circle must mean that you are drawing the shape while not touching the screen, in my code i set `x = -1` when user lifts finger from screen and then on the draw function i test `if (x != -1)` to check if user is touching the screen (you only want to draw circle then) have u done that correctly ?

Comment: I used your code without change anything, only checking if I choose to draw a circle and it works. The problem is I cannot keep the circle drawing on the canvas. I tried adding invalidate() but I cannot keep it drawing.

Comment: @AbelSuviri you should create a new `Bitmap` on the constructor and connect it with a new `Canvas`. Where I say `//Draw circle inside your bitmap here` on the `ACTION_UP`  you should do something like `myCanvas.drawCircle(radius, x, y, paint);` and on the `draw` function you should draw your `Bitmap` that is connected with that canvas.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I did not add the ´drawcircle´ into the ´ACTION_UP´. Tomorrow I will try to draw a rectangle and if I need help I will be back for ask you. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AbelSuviri ok! feel free to ask me if anything goes wrong!